# how can i get data from .js file and update this file

Tags: javascript, api

I don't know if this is the best way but I would like to have a .js file with an object that I will update once a day. I would not like to make a database for this because my code already works for the object. Via API I will get the data for the day and I would like to update the .js file. I would like to keep the historic data in this file and use it to feed the website, the API would only be used at the end of the day. It is a website with data from covid-19, I am doing it just for learning, so I am open to new approaches. I try to keep this file in github, but for edit this i need to put my user and pass in code, i dont know how turn around this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Storing JavaScript objects to files is almost always done in JSON format.

Converting an object to a JSON string is done with the [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) function.

When you read the JSON string back from the file, you covert it back to a JavaScript object with the [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) function.

Comment: Ok, but how can i update this .json file? Ajax or php is the only way? And, think in best pratices, this way is correct?

Comment: Where are you storing this file? On the server?

Comment: At this moment i developing all in localhost, but i want to make the website online. I never do it before, i have no idea how i need to store when this will be online

Comment: Since you mention PHP, here is a minimal example of how to upload a file using PHP: https://gist.github.com/taterbase/2688850